# How to set up react router dom on react vite

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a ReactJS project and need to set up custom paths for my routes. I want to define my own paths instead of relying on the default routes generated by React Router. What is the best way to achieve this in a React application?

Here's a simplified version of my current project structure:

```
/src
  /components
    Home.js
    About.js
  /pages
    HomePage.js
    AboutPage.js
  App.js
  index.js
```

Comment: React Router doesn't generate any default routes. It's not really clear what you're asking or how your own-answer below solves anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement routes to your React app you will need to install `react-router-dom` which will handle the route definition for your application

If you are looking for a general guide on what would be the best idea for creating routes, I would recommend viewing the react-router-dom documentation [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router)

From here you can decide what router would work best for the intent of your app and implement from there. Generally speaking, most devs implement `<BrowserRouter>` to use full URLs within your app. Here is an excerpt from the documentation

> Web Projects We recommend all web projects use createBrowserRouter.
>
> It uses the full URL instead of the hash urls (#this/stuff) common in
> web apps before history.pushState was standardized. Full URLs are
> better for SEO, better for server rendering, and are just more
> compatible with the rest of the web platform.
>
> If you're hosting your app on a static file server, you'll need to
> configure it to send all requests to your index.html to avoid getting
> 404s.
>
> If for some reason you can't use the full URL, createHashRouter is the
> next best thing.
>
> If you're not interested in the data APIs, you can continue to use
>  or, if you can't use full URLs, .

I believe this is as far as I can help you without a more directed approach into what exactly you are looking for. Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

Step 1 :

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

Step 2 :
insert this code on app.jsx

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Test/>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```